# Make clean Syntax error

Tags: c++, makefile, root-framework

When I try to start "make clean" the output is:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
make: *** [clean] Błąd 2


OS = $(shell uname)
CC    = g++
LD    = $(CC)
COPTS    = `root-config --cflags` -fPIC
LDOPTS    = `root-config --glibs`
DEBUG = -g
LD_BOOST_FLAGS = -lboost_program_options -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_regex  
LDOPTS  += $(LD_BOOST_FLAGS)
LDOPTS  += $(DEBUG)
################
UNPACKER_PATH = $(PWD)/framework/JPetUnpacker/
UNPACKER_LIB = Unpacker2
################
SRC_DIR = $(PWD)/framework
#Modules that should have ROOT dictionnaries
DMODULES = JPetAnalysisModule JPetBarrelSlot JPetEvent JPetHit JPetMacroLoader JPetPM JPetScin JPetSigCh JPetSignal JPetTRB JPetTSlot JPetUnpacker JPetFrame JPetFEB JPetLayer JPetSetup  JPetTOMBChannel JPetUser JPetTreeHeader JPetParamBank JPetPMCalib JPetScopeModule
DICTS   = $(DMODULES)
READERS = JPetReader JPetHLDReader JPetScopeReader
WRITERS = JPetWriter
#Modules without ROOT dictionnaries
NONDMODULES = DummyClass JPetLogger JPetCmdParser JPetParamManager JPetManager $(READERS) $(WRITERS) JPetDBParamGetter
MODULES = $(DMODULES) $(NONDMODULES)
################
SRC_MODULES = $(foreach MODULE, $(MODULES), $(SRC_DIR)/$(MODULE)/$(MODULE).cpp) 
SRC_HEADERS = $(SRC_MODULES:.cpp=.h)
################
TEST_DIR = $(SRC_DIR)/tests
################
WORK_DIR = workdir/FrameworkExamples
EXAMPLE_DIRS = $(sort $(dir $(wildcard $(WORK_DIR)/*/)))
################
SOURCES = $(SRC_MODULES)
HEADERS = JPetLoggerInclude.h #Event.h TDCHit.h ADCHit.h Sig.h
HEADERS += $(SRC_HEADERS)
HEADERS += linkdef.h
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
DICT_OBJS = $(foreach DICT, $(DICTS), $(SRC_DIR)/$(DICT)/$(DICT)Dict.o)
################
LIBFRAMEWORK = libJPetFramework.so
LIB_LDOPTS = $(LDOPTS)
OSX_LIB_COPTS += -install_name @rpath/$(LIBFRAMEWORK)
OSX_LIB_LDOPTS = -rpath $(UNPACKER_PATH)
LINUX_LIB_LDOPTS = -Wl,-rpath=$(UNPACKER_PATH)
ifeq ($(OS), Darwin)
    LIB_LDOPTS += $(OSX_LIB_LDOPTS)
else
    LIB_LDOPTS += $(LINUX_LIB_LDOPTS)
endif
LIB_LDOPTS += -L$(UNPACKER_PATH) -l$(UNPACKER_LIB)
################
.cpp.o:
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ -c $(COPTS)
################
all: modules dbhandler
#Dictionary for ROOT classes
Dict.cpp: 
    @echo "Generating dictionary ..."
    @rootcint -f  Dict.cpp -c -P -I$(ROOTSYS) $(HEADERS)
modules:
    @($(foreach MODULE, $(MODULES), cd $(SRC_DIR)/$(MODULE);$(MAKE)||exit $$?;))
sharedlib: modules
    $(LD) -shared -o $(LIBFRAMEWORK) $(OBJECTS) $(DICT_OBJS) $(LIB_LDOPTS);
ifeq ($(OS), Darwin)
    install_name_tool -id @rpath/$(LIBFRAMEWORK) $(LIBFRAMEWORK)
endif
dbhandler:
    cd $(SRC_DIR)/DBHandler; $(MAKE) sharedlib;
################
tests: modules
    cd $(TEST_DIR); $(MAKE)
tests_run: tests
    cd $(TEST_DIR); ./run_tests.pl 
################
documentation:
    doxygen Doxyfile
clean:         
    @rm -rf $(OBJECTS)  $(EXECUTABLE) *.o *.d Dict.cpp Dict.h $(LIBFRAMEWORK) latex html
    @($(foreach MODULE, $(MODULES),$(MAKE) -C $(SRC_DIR)/$(MODULE) clean;))
    @($(foreach EXAMPLE, $(EXAMPLE_DIRS), $(MAKE) -C $(EXAMPLE) clean;))
    $(MAKE) -C $(SRC_DIR)/DBHandler clean
    cd $(TEST_DIR); $(MAKE) clean
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong? I've got some other makefiles where make clean runs OK.
I know that the problem is here:

```
EXAMPLE_DIRS = $(sort $(dir $(wildcard $(WORK_DIR)/*/)))
```

When I comment this line:

```
@($(foreach EXAMPLE, $(EXAMPLE_DIRS), $(MAKE) -C $(EXAMPLE) clean;))
```

`make clean` runs OK, otherwise it gives some error.

Comment: Instead of doing the actual cleaning for the thing that doesn't work, just print out `$(EXAMPLE_DIRS)` to make sure it's correct. Then have the loop, but instead print out `$(EXAMPLE)` to make sure its correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the commands make is sending to the shell.  To debug this, remove the `@` from the beginning of the lines in the `clean` rule and see what the text is.  You'll find an extra `)` and can hopefully figure out why... if not post the output here.

A few notes, though: first, you don't need the outer parenthesis around the `foreach` loops.  In make each recipe line is already run in its own shell, there's no point in creating another subshell here.

Second, you really should quote your arguments (it's even possible this is your problem) when invoking a subshell:

```
clean:         
        rm -rf $(OBJECTS)  $(EXECUTABLE) *.o *.d Dict.cpp Dict.h $(LIBFRAMEWORK) latex html
        $(foreach MODULE, $(MODULES),$(MAKE) -C '$(SRC_DIR)/$(MODULE)' clean;)
        $(foreach EXAMPLE, $(EXAMPLE_DIRS), $(MAKE) -C '$(EXAMPLE)' clean;)
        $(MAKE) -C '$(SRC_DIR)'/DBHandler clean
        $(MAKE) -C '$(TEST_DIR)' clean
```